# Can scripting language and interpreted language force garbage collection?

Tags: garbage-collection, scripting-language, interpreted-language

In javascript, you can't force garbage collection to happen, instead you have to wait for the interpreter to automatically collect it.

Does this behaviour exist in interpreted languages like Python and Java as well?

Comment: At least in Lua, one can call `collectgarbage()` manually.

Comment: @YuHao Java is an interpreted language.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Java, but in Python you can manually force a garbage collection cycle to happen with `gc.collect()`.

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html):

> gc.collect([generation])
>
> With no arguments, run a full collection. The
> optional argument generation may be an integer specifying which
> generation to collect (from 0 to 2). A ValueError is raised if the
> generation number is invalid. The number of unreachable objects found
> is returned.

You can read [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484167/details-how-python-garbage-collection-works) for a reference on how garbage collection works in Python.