# How Long Can Python Run?

Tags: python, python-2.7, memory

I have code like:

```
While 1:
    A = input()
    print A
```

How long can I expect this to run? How many times?

Is there a way I can just throw away whatever I have in A once I have printed it?

How does python deal with it? Will the program crash after a while?

Thank you.

Comment: This is called garbage collection and is done by the python interpreter for you.

Comment: unrelated: you could use `from IPython import embed; embed()` to get `ipython` shell (it looks like your loop tries to emulate Python shell).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Where does that come from?! It’s just a loop that happens to print the input.

Comment: @poke: `input(prompt)` in Python 2 is equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))` (meaning that you can put there any Python expression)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian You are restricted to expressions though, so it’s not the same. And I personally always assume that people post simplified examples here, so that’s probably not all what OP’s doing anyway. Emulating the interpreter is a bit overinterpreted in this case imo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reassign `A` to a new value, there is nothing left referring to the old value. [Garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484167/details-how-python-garbage-collection-works) comes into play here, and the old object is automatically returned back to free memory.

Thus you should never run out of memory with a simple loop like this.

Comment: in theory. In practice some memory may be never released e.g., ["Unfortunately, that free list is both immortal and unbounded in size."](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesnt-python-release-the-memory-when-i-delete-a-large-object.htm)

Answer (score 1):

This can literally run forever. The Python garbage collector will free the memory used by A when it's value is overwritten.

Side note: "While" must be lowercase "while" and it is considered more Pythonic to have "while True:" instead of "while 1:"

Answer (score 0):

You change the value of A so memory wouldn't be an issue as python garbage collects the old value and returns the memory... so forever

Comment: This is wrong in python. `A = input()` reassigns a reference, the now unreferenced object is later garbage-collected.

Comment: I agree, I've added that in.

Comment: But the expression "overwrite the value of A" is still misleading.

Comment: If you see the value of A as a reference to an object, then yes, the value is being overwritten (a new reference is assigned). I think you’re being overly pedantic.

Comment: Python is supposed to be simple hence a simple answer