# Does Python automatically clear up objects?

Tags: python, object, persistence

If I have the following code:

```
populationList = []
for i in range(0, 2000)
    populationList.append(myObject).

populationList = []
```

Would all the objects within populationList get cleaned up now the reference to them has been deleated? I understand that this is the case in Java but it it the same for Python? Or should the objects need to be explicitly deleated?

Comment: Yes *(15 characters)*.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484167/details-how-python-garbage-collection-works

Comment: @BorrajaX: That post is not nearly informative and helpful enough; the garbage collector only deals with circular references. There is no mention there of the reference counting that CPython does.

Comment: Although this is ***sort of*** a duplicate of the garbage collection question...the way it's worded is how someone new to coding would ask it.  I kind of like how it's asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CPython uses *reference counting* to automatically clean up objects that are no longer referenced.

Each name, list index, dictionary value or key entry, or attribute is a reference to a Python object, and the interpreter increments and decrements the reference count on each object as needed. When the count reaches 0, objects are automatically cleared from memory.

When you rebind `populationList` to a *new* list object, the reference count for the old list drops to 0 and it is cleared. That in turn clears all references to the contained objects, and they are cleared too, etc.

A garbage collector process also tracks circular references (objects that only reference one another), breaking such cycles automatically as needed. See the [`gc` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html) for a tool to introspect and alter the behaviour of the garbage collector.

You can hook into the object de-allocation process by implementing a [`__del__` method](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) on your custom class. Do read the documentation to learn about the limitations to this hook.

A quick demo:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self, x):
...         self.x = x
...     def __del__(self):
...         print(self.x, 'deleted')
... 
>>> populationList = []
>>> for i in range(5):
...     populationList.append(Foo(i))
... 
>>> populationList = []
4 deleted
3 deleted
2 deleted
1 deleted
0 deleted
```

Other Python implementations such as Jython and IronPython use different techniques to track objects that can be cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to deleate them by yourself. Python has the similar garbage collection with Java. Some further reading material might be: http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Python_Garbage_Collection and https://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html.

Thanks to @Martijn Pieters: You also be able explicitly disable the gc in Python. BUT should NOT.

Comment: *You also could explicitly disable the gc in Python*. **No you should not**. Not unless you are running time trials on a small piece of code and want to remove the influence of a background task on the timings.