# Python not deleting variable when it goes out of scope

Tags: python

Consider the following code:

```
import random                                                                   

class Trie:                                                                     
    def __init__(self, children, end):                                          
        self.children = children                                                
        self.end = end                                                          

def trie_empty():                                                               
    return Trie(dict(), False)                                                  

def trie_insert(x, t):                                                          
    if not x:                                                                   
        t.end = True                                                            
        return                                                                  
    try:                                                                        
        t2 = t.children[x[0]]                                                   
    except KeyError:                                                            
        t2 = trie_empty()                                                       
        t.children[x[0]] = t2                                                     
    trie_insert(x[1:], t2)                                                      

def fill_dict(root):                                                            
    memo = dict()                                                               
    def fill(pfx='', depth=0):                                                  
        try:                                                                    
            memo[pfx]                                                           
        except KeyError:                                                        
            pass                                                                
        else:                                                                   
            return                                                              
        if depth > 6:                                                           
            return                                                              
        for ci in range(ord('a'), ord('d') + 1):                                
            fill(pfx + chr(ci), depth + 1)                                      
        bw = None                                                               
        memo[pfx] = None, bw                                                    
    fill()                                                                      
    # del memo                                                                  

def random_word():                                                              
    l = int(random.random() * 10)                                               
    w = ''.join([chr(int(random.random() * 26) + ord('a')) for _ in range(l)])  
    return w                                                                    

def main():                                                                     
    t = trie_empty()                                                            
    for _ in range(10000):                                                      
        trie_insert(random_word(), t)                                           

    while True:                                                                 
        fill_dict(t)                                                            

if __name__ == '__main__':                                                      
    main()
```

When I run this, it continues to use more memory until I kill it. If I uncomment the `del memo`, it runs while using a constant amount of memory. From this, I conclude that the local variable `memo` is not being cleaned up when `fill_dict` returns.

This behavior is really mysterious to me, especially because basically all of the above code is necessary to see this behavior. even the *completely unused* argument to `fill_dict` cannot be omitted for the program to use unbounded memory.

This is really frustrating. Surely a modern, garbage-collected language can clean up its own variables and I shouldn't have to manually delete function-local variables. Even C can clean up the stack when a function returns. Why can't Python (in this situation)?

Comment: Why are `trie_empty` and `trie_insert` regular functions instead of methods?

Comment: I suspect this is because you are using a closure (`fill`) and closures are special in that they remember the context in which they are called. Given it uses `memo` it presumably keeps a handle on it so that it doesn't go out of scope.

Comment: @chepner Because I'm not really used to OOP, and it doesn't impact the weird behavior I'm seeing

Comment: `fill` (inside `fill_dict`) is bound to a closure created by calling `fill_dict`, and this closure keeps `memo` alive. What's not clear is what keeps the closure itself alive when `fill_dict` returns. If `root` had a reference to `fill` or one of the things alive inside `fill`, that would be why, but it doesn't.

Comment: Oh I think I know, memo has a reference to bw, which is in fill, and fill has a reference to memo, so it's a circular reference and it never gets cleaned up

Comment: Aha, that's it. Break that reference and the reference-counting GC will clean up. Or you can invoke a full GC, or use a Python implementation that doesn't start with a reference-counting GC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this question deserves an answer, now that between me and Program man—and [match mentioned the same starting point in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54726363/python-not-deleting-variable-when-it-goes-out-of-scope#comment96236796_54726363)—we've figured it out.

The module-level function `fill_dict` has an inner function `fill`:

```
def fill_dict(root):                                                            
    memo = dict()                                                               
    def fill(pfx='', depth=0):
```

This inner name `fill` is bound to the entity created by compiling its contents.  That entity refers back to the name `memo` that is bound to a new, empty dictionary at entry to `fill_dict`, so that entity is itself a [*closure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).

Now, closures *can* be garbage-collected, and Python does have a garbage collector.  But CPython in particular has a two-layer collector: there's a sort of main, always-on, reference-count based collector, and then a true mark-and-sweep style GC that runs much less often.  (See [When does CPython garbage collect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23140705/1256452) and [Why does python use both reference counting and mark-and-sweep for gc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9062209/1256452))

#### Sidebar: what's wrong with reference counting collectors?

A reference-counting collector is defeated by cycles:

```
>>> x = []
>>> x.append(x)
>>> x
[[...]]
```

Here `x` is bound to a list whose first element is the list to which `x` is bound.  That is, x[0] is x, and x[0][0] is x, and so on:

```
>>> x[0] is x
True
>>> x[0][0] is x
True
```

With *this* kind of loop, deleting `x` doesn't help because the list refers to itself.  However, we can make a fancier loop:

```
>>> a = dict()
>>> b = dict()
>>> a['link-to-b'] = b
>>> b['link-to-a'] = a
>>> a
{'link-to-b': {'link-to-a': {...}}}
>>> b
{'link-to-a': {'link-to-b': {...}}}
```

Now if we kill off one of the links, the circularity vanishes:

```
>>> a['link-to-b'] = None
>>> a
{'link-to-b': None}
>>> b
{'link-to-a': {'link-to-b': None}}
```

and things will be fine again.

#### Back to the problem at hand

In this particular case, `fill` has a reference to the `memo` instance in its outer `fill_dict`, and one of the entries *in* `memo` is:

```
        memo[pfx] = None, bw
```

The variable `bw` itself is defined inside the closure, so `memo[pfx]` refers to the closure (or more accurately, to an entity within the closure), while the closure refers to `memo`, and that's our circular reference.

Hence, even when `fill_dict` returns, the reference count on the closure has not dropped to zero.

Comment: Excellent write-up - I got as far as going 'closure! circular reference!' and ran for the hills :-D