# Python Memory Leak Using binascii, zlib, struct, and numpy

Tags: python, memory-leaks

I have a python script which is processing a large amount of data from compressed ASCII.  After a short period, it runs out of memory.  I am not constructing large lists or dicts.  The following code illustrates the issue:

```
import struct
import zlib
import binascii
import numpy as np
import psutil
import os
import gc

process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
n = 1000000
compressed_data = binascii.b2a_base64(bytearray(zlib.compress(struct.pack('%dB' % n, *np.random.random(n))))).rstrip()

print 'Memory before entering the loop is %d MB' % (process.get_memory_info()[0] / float(2 ** 20))
for i in xrange(2):
    print 'Memory before iteration %d is %d MB' % (i, process.get_memory_info()[0] / float(2 ** 20))
    byte_array = zlib.decompress(binascii.a2b_base64(compressed_data))
    a = np.array(struct.unpack('%dB' % (len(byte_array)), byte_array))
    gc.collect()
gc.collect()
print 'Memory after last iteration is %d MB' % (process.get_memory_info()[0] / float(2 ** 20))
```

It prints:

```
Memory before entering the loop is 45 MB
Memory before iteration 0 is 45 MB
Memory before iteration 1 is 51 MB
Memory after last iteration is 51 MB
```

Between the first and second iteration, 6 MB of memory get created.  If i run the loop more than two times, the memory usage stays at 51 MB.  If I put the code to decompress into its own function and feed it the actual compressed data, the memory usage will continue to grow.  I am using Python 2.7.  Why is the memory increasing and how can it be corrected?  Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't say, that is a memory leak, it is normal memory consumption.

Comment: Besides looking quite normal, as @Daniel said, how about the `byte_array` and the `a = np.array`? Your first iteration outputs the memory usage *before* instantiating them. That sounds like a lot of data, which is likely not to be destroyed by the garbage collector because you call it within the `for` loop scope. Unindent (move left) that `gc.collect()` so it runs outside the `for` loop, and see what happens.

Comment: @BorrajaX added another gc.collect before the last print and after the loop exits, no change.  For all the print statements the byte_array and "a" variables shouldnt exist in memory

Comment: sorry, sorry... Even after the `for` loop, `byte_array` and `a` are in your scope (my bad, they don't get destroyed). Right after the loop ends (and before your second `gc.collect()` that you just added) do `byte_array = None` `a=None`... Now I'm curious myself **:-)**

Comment: @BorrajaX added in those set to None statements and it cleared the memory, fixing the concern i had.  I misunderstood Python scoping, I'm more used to Java.  Anyways, i still have an issue in my code but the above example doesn't correctly show it.  Thanks

Comment: I'm gonna add this as an answer so you can choose it and give me juicy reputation **:-D** (if you want, if you waaaAAAAaant ) But yeah, it made me curious, so I did investigate a bit...

Comment: @BorrajaX I'll give you even more rep if you can help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27251451/python-memory-leak-with-struct-and-numpy

Comment: Looks like you figured out yourself. Nice!! **:-)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through comments, we figured out what was going on:

The main issue is that variables declared in a `for` loop are not destroyed once the loop ends. They remain accessible, pointing to the value they received in the last iteration:

```
>>> for i in range(5):
...     a=i
...
>>> print a
4
```

So here's what's happening:

- First iteration: The `print` is showing 45MB, which the memory *before* instantiating `byte_array` and `a`.
- The code instantiates those two lengthy variables, making the memory go to 51MB
- Second iteration: The two variables instantiated in the first run of the loop are still there.
- In the middle of the second iteration, `byte_array` and `a` are overwritten by the new instantiation. The initial ones are destroyed, but substituted by equally lengthy variables.
- The `for` loop ends, but `byte_array` and `a` are still accessible in the code, therefore, not destroyed by the second `gc.collect()` call.

Changing the code to:

```
for i in xrange(2):
   [ . . . ]
byte_array = None
a = None
gc.collect()
```

made the memory resreved by `byte_array` and `a` unaccessible, and therefore, freed.

There's more on Python's garbage collection in this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4484312/289011

Also, it may be worth looking at [How do I determine the size of an object in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449560/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-an-object-in-python). This is tricky, though... if your object is a list pointing to other objects, what is the *size*? The sum of the pointers in the list? The sum of the size of the objects those pointers point to?