# Python list object in memory, for how long?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a web service and at a point a user runs a python script saving a list of strings `UserList` in my server's memory. The user surfs around the site doing other stuff and at the same time other concurrent users use the web service saving also other instances of this `UserList` object. My question is for how long will these objects stay in my server's memory? Shall I do anything to get rid of them, or my `OS` takes care of that issue?

Comment: How/where are the lists saved?  Does the web service run a separate process for each request/connection or does it handle everything in one process?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484167/details-how-python-garbage-collection-works) might help.

Comment: @jwodder : Sessions exist. Each user is authenticated with a token when logged in, so when two list objects are created for two different users, they occupy two different locations in memory.

Comment: @Vlad : Thank you very much `Vlad`, I will study it...