# Why do I need to keep a variable pointing to my QWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt4

Why does the example below only work if the useless `_` variable is created?

The `_` variable is assigned and never used. I would assume a good compiler would optimize and not even create it, instead it does make a difference.

If I remove `_ =` and leave just `Test()`, then the window is created, but it flickers and disappears immediately, and python hangs forever.

Here is the code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Test(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.show()

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
_ = Test()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You mean `Test()` instead of `Example()`?

Comment: If a Python object isn't referenced, it is garbage collected, which would explain why the window flickers then disappears.

Comment: So a variable that your program won't work without is "useless"?

Comment: `I would assume a good compiler would optimize and not even create it` - python is not compiled and doesn't have a compiler. It will do exactly what you tell it. Also, function calls and object creation can have arbitrary side effects, for example `class Evil(object): def __init__(self): import os; os.rmdir('/')`

Comment: Re: "assume a good compiler would optimize and not even create it" -- any module-scoped assignment has side effects, inasmuch as it's... well... *creating a variable in the module*. That variable can be dynamically searched for by code that doesn't exist yet, potentially code outside the module.

Comment: ...if this were C, then you'd be creating a variable that could be linked to by other object files, so the compiler couldn't optimize it away -- which is to say that there's no implicit `static` for module-scoped variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a very good question and I've faced a lot of weird problems in the past because of this fact with my PyQt widgets and plugins, basically that happens thanks to the [python garbage collector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484167/python-garbage-collector-documentation/4484312#4484312).

When you assign your instance to that `_` dummy variable before entering the Qt's main loop, there will be a living reference that will avoid to be collected by the garbage collector, therefore the widget won't be destroyed.

Comment: Does that mean that if I want to create the window inside a method of a non-global object, then the window would be destroyed as soon as the object goes out of scope? And if I wanted to (I don't know for what reason) I would need to assign it to a global variable?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it means.

Answer (score 0):

@BPL is correct, but I wanted to add that you don't have to assign it to _. You can assign it to whatever variable you like. You just need a variable referencing to the object you created, otherwise it's collected by the garbage collector after being created.