# Numpy: garbage collection after slicing

Tags: python, numpy, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, numpy-ndarray

```
def foo():
    x = np.ones((10,10))
    return x[:5,:5]
```

If I call `y = foo()` I'll get a 5x5 array (1/4 of the values in `x`). But what happens to the other values in `x`, do they persist in memory or get garbage collected in some way? I'd like to understand this.

Comment: Possibly a useful read: [Python garbage collector documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484167/python-garbage-collector-documentation/4484312)

Comment: Basic slicing of a NumPy array creates a view of the array ,which retains a reference to the original array. The original array must be kept around for the slice to make any sense. The array named `x` will stick around as long as its slice view does. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: @kindall do you have a reference on that? I'm not very familiar with numpy internals and would be interested in learning more

Comment: The link I posted outlines basic vs. advanced indexing, and notes that basic indexing creates a view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As kindall says in the comments, [basic slicing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) on a NumPy array creates a view of the original array. The view has to keep the entire original object alive; you can see the reference it uses to do so in the view's `base` attribute.

```
In [2]: x = numpy.ones((10, 10))

In [3]: y = x[:5, :5]

In [4]: y.base is x
Out[4]: True
```

Comment: Worth noting that `y = y.copy()` will cause `x` to be cleaned up

Comment: Even if x goes out of scope?

Comment: @Nic: Object lifetimes have no scope. Variables have scope, but variables are not objects.

Comment: Isn't `x` a variable that points to the ndarray? When `x` goes out of scope doesn't the garbage collector call some kind of dispose function on it? That's my question - is the entire ndarray preserved because of `y`?

Comment: Yes, the entire array is preserved because of `y`. The garbage collector isn't involved here; this is a simple case of reference counting. `x` is a reference to the array, and `y` is a view which contains a reference to the array. When `x` goes away, there's still a reference somewhere within `y`. The array isn't disposed of until its reference count is zero, which it's not. If `y` goes out of scope, though, the view will be disposed of, which will allow the array to be disposed of.